# VueJS 2 $emit and $on

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use VueJS 2 and I really don't figure out how communicate from child component to parent.

I have 2 components : **Dashboad** and **DashboardPanel**.

In **DashboardPanel**, I have one method :

```
execute () {
    // emit to parent
    this.$emit('executeSQL', this.value)
    ...
}
```

And in **Dashboard** :

```
mounted () {
   // get event from DashboardPanel
   this.$on('executeSQL', function(value) {
        alert(value)
   })
}
```

Nothing happens, I don't find in doc where to use **$on** and I don't know if I can use other way to achieve it ?

Comment: Assuming, DashboardPanel is the child component, did you try `this.$parent.$emit` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify in `Dashboard` component how to react to `executeSQL` event from `DashboardPanel` component. In the HTML template of `Dashboard`:

```
<DashboardPanel v-on:executeSQL="doExecuteSQL($event)" />
```

`doExecuteSQL` beeing a method of `Dashboard`:

```
methods: {
  doExecuteSQL(value) { ... }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes I used this method, but I don't understand why the $on event doesn't work in JS

Comment: `$on` is for listening for events emitted by the same component. So `this.$on('executeSQL')` would work in the DashboardPanel component but doesn't work in the Dashboard component